# How can I set the coordinates of the Hypercube? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, computer-science

So, we have a homework question that asks us to create a hypercube of corners 2^n. And each corner has a set of n-coordinates in a plane of x1, x2, x3... xn. So, a n=3 hypercube has coordinates such as:
000, 001, 011, 010, etc. in a plane x1, x2, x3.

The point of writing this program is so have a recursive method and an iterative method to "walk" through the hypercube and pass every corner exactly once without overlapping it's trail. The professor also demand that our Corner object be a nested class in the hypercube class. So far this is what I've come up with:

ublic class Hypercube 
{

```
private Corner[] walk;
private int size;
private final int ZERO  = 0;
private int count;

public Hypercube(int n) throws IllegalHypercubeException {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalHypercubeException("Please enter a positive integer");
    } else {
        this.size = n;
        this.count = 0;
        this.walk = new Corner[(int) Math.pow(2, n)];
    }
}

public class Corner 
{

    private int[] coordinates;

    public Corner() {
        this.coordinates = new int[size];

    }this.coordinates = coordinates;

}
```

I find most difficulty in setting the coordinates before I can even order them recursively in the walk methods. How am I meant to set all the coordinates of each corner of a cube of 2^n corners?

Answer (score 1):

Not going to write a code for it (that's you job), but here's something to orient you:

In a 1D - the corners will be {0} and {1}

In 2D - the corners will be

```
{
  {0,0}, {0,1}, 
  {1,0}, {1,1}
}
```

In 3D - the corners will be

```
{
   {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {0,1,1},
   {1,0,0}, {1,0,1}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,1}
}
```

If you still haven't had your *Aha!* moment, here's the spoiler: make a list of corners in N-dimension by prefixing the all the corners in a N-1 dimension by `0` then by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

When you walk through hypercube by it's edges, you change one coordinate at every step. Note there are special binary sequences where exactly one bit is flipped between neighbor elements.

Look at [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) (n-bit code for n-dimensional hypercube)- they are well described, numerous methods exist to generate sequence both recursively and iteratively.

Comment: What's a problem? Just use n-but Gray code, as I said